# Data transformation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures

- Input data are lists of 1-D numpy arrays e.g. `x[0] = [ array([1.0,1.0,1.0]), array([2.0,2.0,2.0]), ...]`
- `len(x)` is on the order of a few thousand (rows) while `len(x[n])` is a fixed number (columns), but may change from run to run (so I don't want to hard-code a number of columns).
- Function `f(x[n][col])` transforms each `array` into a single number
- Desired result is a list of transformed columns

The lists are for plotting, so they could be a numpy data structure.
Here is some code to set up test data and notional transformation:

```
import numpy

# create test data set
def datagen(number):
    return numpy.array([number,number,number])

x=[]
for rows in range(20):
    dataline = [ datagen(n) for n in range(5)]
    x.append(dataline)

#define transformation of array to single number
def f(in_array):
    return in_array.sum()
```

Desired result-- get in a numpy, pythonic sort of way:

```
[ array([0,0,0,...0]), array([3,3,3,....,3]), array([6,6,6,...,6]), ..etc]
```

where in this case each array has 20 elements (one for each row of data) and there are 5 arrays in the list (one for each column).

Here is my current solution:

```
trans = []
for dataline in x:
    trans.append([f(a) for a in dataline])

trans = numpy.array(trans)
answer = [ trans[:,col] for col in range(len(x[0])) ]
```

Not too shabby but my head hurts and I have a feeling this can be done better. ???

In real life f(a) = `numpy.sqrt(numpy.vdot(a,a))`.

Comment: What does `f` look like?  To vectorise a function, we need to know what the function does.

Comment: Hi Sven, it's the magnitude of the vector (post edited).

Comment: Do you really need to use lists of numpy arrays?  If you were just using a 3D array to begin with this would be a one-liner.  (`ndarray.sum` can easily operate along a single axis.)

Comment: I'll give it a try, Joe, thanks.  My lists of numpy arrays originate from low-dimensional thinking.  :o

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
numpy.tile(numpy.arange(1,12).reshape(11,1),20)
```

Comment: More numpy/matlab-ish than pythonic, I guess.

Comment: Can you rephrase in terms of `x` and `f()`?

Comment: Ah, right now I read the start of your question properly. My bad, I was short-cutting to the desired result and ignoring the input. You probably want to vectorize your functions http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html if you want to avoid the loops, but I don't have time right now to test it out...